# How can I define custom _repr_*_ methods in IJulia notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

When using IPython notebook, I can [define a custom method `_repr_*_` on my object](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/display_protocol.ipynb) that allows it to be rendered in a different form (e.g. a png) to a user.

I'd like to do the same in Julia using IJulia notebook.  Specifically, I have a type that I'd like to always be represented by a PNG when displayed in the notebook.  How can I achieve this?  (I tried grepping for `repr` in the IJulia repository, but this has not been helpful so far.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define something for `writemime`, e.g.

```
type MyType
  foo
end

Base.writemime(io::IO, ::MIME"text/latex", x::MyType) = write(io, "\$\$ $(x.foo) \$\$")
```

For LaTeX output. The MIME type for `png` is `"image/png"`. Here is, e.g. [Winston.jl writing a `png` to `io`](https://github.com/nolta/Winston.jl/blob/6cc73b7debbc8f9d43e55142caeccb105b917e0d/src/Winston.jl#L2629).